# Coldfusion: Getting NullPointerException trying to edit spreadsheet

Tags: excel, coldfusion

I've got a template spreadsheet I want to edit so I can insert data into it.

However this code which apparently should work just throws a NullPointerException instead. The error always occurs on the 'write' portion of the code. The spreadsheet is read in fine.

```
<!--- Read spreadsheet --->
    <cfspreadsheet action="read"
    src="#theFileCopy#"
    name="sObj" />
    <!--- Set cell value --->
    <cfset spreadsheetSetCellValue(sObj, "Test", 3, 3)>
    <!--- Write spreadsheet --->
    <cfspreadsheet action="write" overwrite="true"
    filename="#theFileCopy#"
    name="sObj" />
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString.toCTFont(XSSFRichTextString.java:458)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString.getFontOfFormattingRun(XSSFRichTextString.java:397)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.getColumnWidth(ColumnHelper.java:368)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:337)
at coldfusion.excel.Excel.autoResize(Excel.java:1336)
at coldfusion.excel.Excel.autoResize(Excel.java:1327)
at coldfusion.excel.Excel.writeExcel(Excel.java:4824)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.SpreadSheetTag.writeToExcel(SpreadSheetTag.java:237)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.SpreadSheetTag.doStartTag(SpreadSheetTag.java:157)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
at cfRelocationForm2ecfc1823847668$funcPRODUCERELOCATIONFORM.runFunction(C:\websites\msft\msft_webcore_frontend\modules\moves\model\core\reports\RelocationForm.cfc:137)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:655)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:444)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:414)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2432)
at cfReports2ecfc1819002159$funcGETRELOCATIONFORM.runFunction(C:\websites\msft\msft_webcore_frontend\modules\moves\api\core\Reports.cfc:101)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368)
at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:518)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:660)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:469)
at coldfusion.filter.ComponentFilter.invoke(ComponentFilter.java:193)
at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:442)
at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.invoke(CFCServlet.java:155)
at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doGet(CFCServlet.java:289)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:204)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What happens when you cfdump variables sObj and thefilecopy?

Comment: I get a dumo of information about the spreadsheet object though nothing about whats inside it. The filecopy is just the filepath

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the file was in xlsx format. For some reason Coldfusion will read in an xslx fine but will not write it back out. The docs do say spreadsheet action=write only does xls. Would love to know any methods for doing this.

Comment: With version 9 something I just ran this code and got the expected workbook.  <cfquery name="x" datasource="dw">
table event
</cfquery>
<cfspreadsheet action="write" query="x" filename="abc.xlsx">

Comment: Yeah it works fine with queries but i'm creating a spreadsheet object since that contains all the nice formatting of the template.